# How to write windows installation iso to usb hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-installation, usb-storage

There seem to be many tools to write an ISO to a USB stick, but I am trying to write a windows installation ISO to an external hard drive, many tools don't even list it as an option to write to, what options do I have?

Answer (score 5):

Finally found one, Rufus (windows) will do it if you go to "Show advanced drive properties" and check "List USB Hard Drives".

Comment: Yes, this is indicated [in the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#help-my-usb-drive-is-not-detected). The reason why external HDDs are not listed by default [is also explained in the FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-rufus-list-external-hdds-by-default).